# moving into unique_ptr container

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have something I want to do that is extremely similar to the code snippet at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) for unique_ptr. The snippet is produced below. It compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> s{"one", "two", "three"};

    std::vector<std::string> v1(s.begin(), s.end()); // copy

    std::vector<std::string> v2(std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
                                std::make_move_iterator(s.end())); // move

    std::cout << "v1 now holds: ";
    for (auto str : v1)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";
    std::cout << "\nv2 now holds: ";
    for (auto str : v2)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";
    std::cout << "\noriginal list now holds: ";
    for (auto str : s)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

What I really want is move the strings from s into a **vector of unique_ptr**.

so something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> v2(&std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
                                &std::make_move_iterator(s.end()));`

but this of course does not work.

I can only get it to do what I want with this bit of code:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> s{"one", "two", "three"};

    std::vector<std::string> v1(s.begin(), s.end()); // copy

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> v2;
    for(auto& o : s)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<std::string> p ( new std::string(move(o)));
        v2.push_back(move(p));
    }

    std::cout << "\nv2 now holds: ";
    for (auto& pstr : v2)
            std::cout << "\"" << *pstr << "\" ";
    std::cout << "\noriginal list now holds: ";
    for (auto str : s)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Is there a way to move resources into a container of unique_ptrs in one line?

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you use a `make_unique` function as Herb Sutter recommends you can do:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T> ( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> s{"one", "two", "three"};

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> v2;
    std::transform(begin(s), end(s), std::back_inserter(v2),
            &make_unique<std::string, std::string&>
    );
}
```

I have lifted `make_unique` from Herbs page on the matter, it is included with C++14 or just use this version.

http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Unfortunately we can't use type deduction so we have to provide the types manually.

Comment: OP wants to move, not copy - so maybe transform with `[](std::string& s){return make_unique<std::string>(std::move(s));}`

Comment: Oh, and he wants it in one line - so mash that entire `std::transform` call into one huge line ;)